# Socket.Io not firing any events in Chrome

Tags: angular, socket.io

I'm trying to build up a Socket.IO connection in my Angular application but just can't get it to work! Here is my current code:

```
    import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

    var sock = io('http://my.socket.server', {
        reconnectionAttempts: 10,
    });
    sock.on('connect', () => { console.log('connect'); });
    sock.on('reconnect_attempt', () => { console.log('recon'); });
    sock.on('reconnecting', () => { console.log('recon'); });
    sock.onAny(() => { console.log('any'); });
    sock.close();
```

I can see that the browser is trying to connect and I can even set reconnection attempts - so *something* seams to work. But none of my `on` appender is called! It's probably an absolute trivial issue ...

Thank you!

Edit: Tried this code now and I see no events either:

```
    var sock = io('https://socketio-chat-h9jt.herokuapp.com/', {
        reconnectionAttempts: 5,
    });

    sock.on('connection', sock => {
        alert(1);
        sock.on('connect', () => { console.log('connect'); });
        sock.on('reconnect_attempt', () => { console.log('recon'); });
        sock.on('reconnecting', () => { console.log('recon'); });
        sock.onAny(() => { console.log('any'); });
        sock.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the client side then, according to the socket.io documentation https://socket.io/docs/v3/index.html, the syntax is supposed to go like

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

so all the socket.on functions should be inside a bigger io.on('connection') function.

Comment: So there is no possibility to get connection errors if no connection is established at all?

Comment: Yes, if this is the client-side javascript.